# How to Print Unified Python Dictionary Within For Loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, ini, configparser

I try to print one unified Python dictionary with the section's details from the **Config.ini** file but Unfortunately I get separate lists or only the final dict.

I'd love to get some help from you guys.

```
config_path = r"<Path>\Config.ini"

    dict = {}

    config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
    config.read(config_path)
    sections = config.sections()

    for section in sections:
        sql_query = config.get(section, 'SQL')
        limit = config.get(section, 'Limit')
        description = config.get(section, 'Description')
        section_name = section

        dict = {'Query': sql_query,
                'Limit': limit,
                'Description': description,
                'Section': section_name}

    print dict
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You override your dictionary in each loop.

### Version 1: List of dicts

```
config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
config.read(config_path)
sections = config.sections()

config_sections = []
for section in sections:
    config_sections.append(
        {'Query': config.get(section, 'SQL'),
         'Limit': config.get(section, 'Limit'),
         'Description': config.get(section, 'Description'),
         'Section': section})

print config_sections
```

### Version 2: Dict with lists

```
config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
config.read(config_path)
sections = config.sections()

config_dict = {}
for section in sections:
    for name, value in [('Query', config.get(section, 'SQL')),
                        ('Limit', config.get(section, 'Limit')),
                        ('Description', config.get(section, 'Description')),
                        ('Section', [section])]:
        config_dict.setdefault(name, []).append(value)
print config_dict
```

Comment: Thanks Mike for your help :)                                                                 but according to your code I'm getting this output {Query[all_sections_queries], Limit[all_sections_limit]....}.                 What I need is this output                           {[query1,limit1,description1,section1],[query2,limit2,description2,section2],[query3,limit3,description3,section3]}

Comment: I thought this what you want. Do you ant a list with one dictionary per section?

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, and that's exactly what I need.

Comment: You can [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) an answer if it solves your problem.